# 2 windows loaders after grub2 repair

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I have recently reinstalled w7 and had ubuntu 12.04 lts installed on it,w7 installation deleted the grub2 loader,after that i found solution to use boot-repair from live-cd session, BUT......now i have 2 windows 7(loader)in grub loader,and only 1 windows 7 installation,how can i remove it?One is on on /dev/sda1(which should be w7 sistem reserved partition) and second is on on /dev/sda2(which is w7 installment partition) it says and both log on same w7.All i need is to remove it without brake the grub2 again and if someone is willing to guide me to add windows on primary selection, cause my girlfriends doesnt get along with linux :D.

Boot info URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1291403

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1291403/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to remove the `Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)` entry: delete (or rename) the `/bootmgr` file and `/Boot` folder which are in the **sda1** partition, then run `sudo update-grub` from within Ubuntu.
2. If you want to remove the `Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)` entry: delete (or rename) the `/bootmgr` file and `/Boot` folder which are in the **sda2** partition, then run `sudo update-grub` from within Ubuntu.

Comment: don't forget to validate my answer ;)